# NewtonSoft JSON.NEt 7.0.1

Tags: serialization, datatable, json.net, type-conversion

Previously I have been serializing DataTables with simply JsonConvert.Serialize(oMyTable), in version 6.0.8 which works just fine, I updated today to 7.0.1 and if I run my webservice method via invoke on the web site, the return values are just as before. However, if I call the exact same instance of the webservice from an application, it isn't invoking the DataTableConverter and I get the serialized result containing all the properties of a DataTable object. It seems to not run the DataTableConverter, anyone else having a similar problem? Yes, the DataTable has rows and it also has a name. I noticed some changes to the DataTableConverter mentioned in the 7.0.1 release, did something change that would cause the converter not to be invoked as it was previously?

Thanks
Alan

Code that previously worked (and still does using 6.0.8):

```
public string GetZoneConfiguration(int iZoneId)
{
  string sOutput = string.Empty;

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.RFIDConnection))
  {
    oLog.Error("{0}, no RFIDConnection value.", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    return sOutput;
  }

  DBUtility oDatabase = new DBUtility(this.RFIDConnection);

  string sSQL = "select zone_id, zone_org, zone_name, zone_type, read_time, read_cycles, sensor_bounce_time, sensor_method, filter, reader_id, reader_name, reader_tcp_address from vw_rfid_zone_readers";
  sSQL += " where zone_id = " + iZoneId.ToString() + " and reader_active = 1";
  DataTable oTable = new DataTable("ZoneConfiguration");
  if (!oDatabase.ReadData(sSQL, ref oTable))
  {
     oLog.Error("{0}, ReadData returned {1}.", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, oDatabase.SQLError);
  }
  sOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oTable);
  return sOutput;
```

}

Comment: Returned: <string xmlns="http://">
[{"zone_id":1,"zone_org":"RAI","zone_name":"AL Shipping","zone_type":1,"read_time":3,"read_cycles":10,"sensor_bounce_time":4,"sensor_method":"GPIOEDGE","filter":"3014DBA424","reader_id":1,"reader_name":"AL Shipping1","reader_tcp_address":"TCP://10.115.116.52:2189"},{"zone_id":1,"zone_org":"RAI","zone_name":"AL Shipping","zone_type":1,"read_time":3,"read_cycles":10,"sensor_bounce_time":4,"sensor_method":"GPIOEDGE","filter":"3014DBA424","reader_id":2,"reader_name":"AL Shipping2","reader_tcp_address":"TCP://10.115.116.53:2189"}]
</string>

Answer (score 0):

I too have had problems with code that worked in an old version but doesn't in the latest version. I just rolled back, on Nuget you can still install the older versions which is nice!